# Should data be split into test / training prior to descriptive statistics being carried out on it?

Tags: categorical-data, dataset, descriptive-statistics

I have a data set that I have added to and plan to carry out some modelling with. I'm wondering whether I should split the data into test / training prior to carrying out the modelling, or if I should write the descriptive section out first *then* split into test/training for the modelling part.

The descriptive stuff is going to be things like percentiles, some $\chi^2$ between different levels, basics like this.

The data is mainly categorical, there are around 700 rows and 30 columns. 
I'm planning to carry out logistic regression and (probably) a decision tree.

Answer (score 4):

Data splitting often requires a sample size exceeding 20,000 to work properly, i.e., to be stable.  Otherwise re-splitting the data will result in arbitrary changes of the model and also of the validation stats.  And note that decision trees are not competitive with logistic regression.  The bootstrap or repeated cross-validation are preferred.  See my RMS [book and course notes](http://fharrell.com/links).

In terms of what you can do before model validation, anything that is masked to Y is fair game.  So you can do descriptive statistics that do not examine associations between X and Y.

Comment: Thank's Frank. So here you're suggesting suggesting that test/training with 700 rows is pointless? In your course notes though (Data splitting, 5.3.3 from : http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) you give an example of a dataset with 300 elements, where the training is 200 and the test is 100. I'm still not too sure whether, in this example, you would carry out descriptive statistics on the data prior to splitting or not.

Comment: What empirical evidence do you have to support the “20,000” sample size requirement? That seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: I thought I was clear regarding which kinds of descriptive statistics are OK.  Regarding the 20,000 that comes from work I did where a 17,000 patient dataset with 0.3 mortality was not large enough to prevent data splitting from giving an arbitrary result.  I'm not saying the modeling and validation are fruitless here.  I'm just saying that model building should not sacrifice sample size and model validation should use resampling methods, repeating all steps using Y afresh for each iteration.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I didn't find it clear, and the notes that you linked seemed to contradict what you've written in your original post (to me).

Comment: Tell me the nature of the contradiction and what is unclear about the notes.

Comment: In the post you've mentioned 20,000 but not explained why. In the notes you have n = 300 for splitting. For myself that is contradictory in this context. I've probably missed something, but I'm not experienced. In the explanation about whether or not descriptives can be done you mention about anything 'masked to Y', I'm not familiar with this expression. Are you saying that anything which isn't ultimately used in the model can be used in the descriptives?

Comment: Nowhere in the notes is n=300 given as a sample size requirement.  You are probably confusing that with 300 bootstrap repetitions (I usually recommend 400 unless the sample size is in the hundreds of thousands, then fewer bootstraps suffice).  Descriptives on anything are OK if not used for model building.  Otherwise hide descriptive associations with Y (make the analysis masked/blinded to Y).

Comment: @FrankHarrell: I just looked at your notes too; while nothing about $n=300$ as a sample size requirement is mentioned, the notes read: "overall sample $n
= 300$, training sample $n = 200$, develop model, freeze $\hat{\beta}$, predict on test sample ( $n = 100$ )". Reading this *and your comments* here I suspect you mean to say to repeat this procedure several hundred times. But definitely this not clearly in by looking at your notes in isolation. If anything, in the notes these lines come under then "Data Splitting" and are mentioned separately from CV and/or Bootstrap.

Comment: You are misreading the notes.  The subsection on data splitting is distinct from the one for resampling procedures.  Data splitting does not involve resampling; it only involves a single sampling process from the original sample (here n=300 chosen purely as a made-up example).  The subsection on data split is in the notes primarily to advise readers against the use of data splitting; but they need to know what it is.  The many disadvantages are clearly laid out.  I guess I need to add there **DON'T DO IT**.